# Mysql user creation script

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to automate MySQL user creation procedure.
I thought of creating a temp file that would contain mysql user creation statements,
then I would have call it like this :

mysql -u root -proot < temp

But I'm stuck with mysql syntax :
here's the content of my temp file :

---

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mytestdatabase;
CREATE DATABASE mytestdatabase;
SELECT @password:="my password";
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='mytestdatabase';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytestdatabase.* TO 'mytestdatabase'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '@password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

---

But the line

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytestdatabase.* TO 'mytestdatabase'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '@password';
```

(Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number )

is not interpreted as I would expect it to be.
Even if I remove single quotes around the @password tag I still have errors (syntax error)

How can I make this work ?

Comment: ERROR 1372 (HY000) at line 9: Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just to answer why the error occurs and to show the differnce:

---

**A) Expects `@password` to be a *hash string <sup>1</sup>* value:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
    ON `mydb` . * TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
BY
PASSWORD '@password';
```

<sup>*Note the use of the `PASSWORD` keyword!*</sup>

---

**B) Expects `@password` to be a *clear-text string* value:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
    ON `mydb` . * TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
BY
'@password';
```

<sup>*Note the **missing** `PASSWORD` keyword!*</sup>

---

***<sup>1</sup>** Where "hash string" is the result of `SELECT PASSWORD('clearTextPasswd');` - see [Snowman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969983/624466) for an example.*

Answer (score 13):

If you do not want to store password in clear text, then save it in hashed format -

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytestdatabase.* TO 'mytestdatabase'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7560636C2922C05954FE6A2446AA00C84708B57B';
```

Where hashed password is a result of this query -

```
SELECT PASSWORD('my password');
```

Answer (score 8):

I have also got same problem, it is resolved just by setting the password by mentioned query below.

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the following url and this will help you to fix the issue:

http://linuxadministrator.pro/blog/?p=147

```
mysql> select password('12345');
+-------------------------+
| password('123456') |
+-------------------------+
| 2ff898e158cd0311        |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user test identified by password '2ff898e158cd0311';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytestdatabase.* 
      TO mytestdatabase@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

where PASSWORD is your password (in quotes).

Comment: Yes it would work, but I heard it is less secure since the password can appears in a mysql history file in clear form. I would prefer to avoid this solution whenever possible.

Comment: Then you can set it as I showed and then change it like this: SET PASSWORD FOR mytestdatabase= PASSWORD('PASSWORD');

Comment: the clear form of the password still appears, but maybe because it's called from a file it won't be logged in the "mysql history". I may try to get more infos how that "mysql history" really works. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/disable-mysql-history-clear-mysql_history-and-mysql_histfile/

Answer (score 0):

I opened phpMYAdmin and went to the the users tab, found the user i was trying to connect with clicked Edit Privileges, scrolled down to the Change Login Information / Copy User section and choose **Any host** for the Host option, it was set to local.  When I clicked the Go button, it generated a script similar to the ones listed here.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'james'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*780E1D13F1C7713F341A117499C6D8644464C4CF' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well hat is error bcoz you have wrote the wrong way just you have wrote,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '@password';
```

and the true syntax is follows. look here.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '@password';
```

because your password is causing that error. it must be in as shown.