# MySql - Script to create user and database with hashed password

Tags: mysql

Following the instructions at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529651/mysql-user-creation-script/15969983#15969983), I'm trying to use the following syntax to create an user with a password

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS forum;
CREATE DATABASE forum;
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='forum_admin';
#In this way, the password will not be logged in mysql history
SELECT @password:=PASSWORD('forum_admin');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON forum.* TO 'forum_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '@password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However, the penultimate instruction gives this error

```
ERROR 1827 (HY000): The password hash doesn't have the expected format. Check if the correct password algorithm is being used with the PASSWORD() function.
```

So, how can I solve? I don't want to manually insert the result of the `SELECT @password` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529919/2326627) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969983/2326627) for example), but I'd like to use those result to create automatically a new user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You dont need to create the hash, the passwords are already stored as hash..
This is how a new user is created

```
 create user forum_admin@'localhost'  identified by 'password' ;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON forum.* TO 'forum_admin'@'localhost';
 flush privileges;
```

In your code:
Change

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON forum.* TO 'forum_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pass_string';
```

to

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON forum.* TO 'forum_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass_string';
```

Comment: oh wait, now it seems just a stupid question :S Haven't noticed the PASSWORD item at all.
Btw, on a comment in the first link of my answer
"it is less secure since the password can appears in a mysql history file in clear form." Is it untrue?

Comment: @tigerjack89 ya that is a good point...Create a file, name it as createUser.sql ... write all the mentioned queries in it... save it.... load the sql file via command line ... mysql -uroot -p databasename < createUser.sql ...here the database name will be mysql...

Comment: I initially thought it's an optional keyword like `GRANT ALL [PRIVILEGES]` but it wasn't. It seems to just call the `password` function on the string provided. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Answer (score 7):

I meet this problem too. May be you should get your password hash value

```
mysql> select password('1');
+-------------------------------------------+
| password('1')                             |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

then excute the grant command

```
mysql> grant all 
-> on *.*
-> to xiushanfan identified by password '*xxxxxxxxxxx(copy from above)' 
-> with grant option;
```

Everything will be ok.

Here is the link:http://shareolite.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-solve-mysql-error-1827-hy000.html

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me.  I wasn't aware of the select password('.......') option.  This fixed the misleading problem of 'database not selected' error you sometimes get.  It is really a privileges issue and the above fixes it. Thanks .

Comment: Also important to note is that due to the keyword 'password' this command is not logged within the `.mysql_history` file by default. So you dont need to take care of cleanup to keep your password secret.